# How to design 4 clickable circular fields in android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview, android-xml

This should be a very simple fun-game where you can pick 2 colors and your friend has to guess which one you've picked. I basically want my Activity to look like this:

[image]

Each quarter should be clickable with a onClick-Animation (I guess it can't be a Button if it should look like this)

What's the best way to get to this result with a XML Code?
I was thinking about a ConstraintLayout with ImageViews, but with instead of getting the circle shape clickable, I get a rectangle of clickable area.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgThree"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imgTwo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="NEW ITEM"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imgOne"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imgTwo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgTwo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorblue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgFour"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imgOne"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="NEW ITEM"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imgTwo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imgTwo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgThree"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorGreen"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imgTwo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgOne" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="NEW ITEM"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imgThree"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imgFour"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFour"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imgThree"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgTwo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="NEW ITEM"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imgThree"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imgTwo" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This could be done with Picasso creating a circular image, but that feels more like a workaround and not a solution.

Comment: Checkout my answer below, Tick it or consider an acception if it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the trick, 
you can create this just using xml layouts**

First create 4 vector path shapes in drawable Folder

**ic_top_left.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="180dp"
    android:height="180dp"
    android:viewportWidth="250"
    android:viewportHeight="250">
  <group>
    <clip-path
        android:pathData="M0,0h250v250h-250z"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M240,240L15,240a226.612,226.612 0,0 1,4.571 -45.346A223.763,223.763 0,0 1,53.426 114.2a225.659,225.659 0,0 1,98.993 -81.518,223.933 223.933,0 0,1 42.235,-13.11A226.68,226.68 0,0 1,240 15L240,240Z"
        android:fillColor="#F8675D"/>
  </group>
</vector>
```

**ic_top_right.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="180dp"
    android:height="180dp"
    android:viewportWidth="250"
    android:viewportHeight="250">
  <group>
    <clip-path
        android:pathData="M0,0h250v250h-250z"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M10,15l-0,-0a226.76,226.76 135,0 1,45.344 4.572,223.929 223.929,0 0,1 42.235,13.11A225.077,225.077 0,0 1,135.8 53.427,226.632 226.632,135 0,1 169.1,80.9a226.592,226.592 135,0 1,27.474 33.3A224.976,224.976 135,0 1,217.318 152.421,223.788 223.788,45 0,1 230.428,194.655 226.613,226.613 0,0 1,235 240L10,240L10,15Z"
        android:fillColor="#5699ff"/>
  </group>
</vector>
```

**ic_bott_left.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="180dp"
    android:height="180dp"
    android:viewportWidth="250"
    android:viewportHeight="250">
  <group>
    <clip-path
        android:pathData="M0,0h250v250h-250z"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M240,235h0a226.76,226.76 0,0 1,-45.344 -4.572,223.929 223.929,0 0,1 -42.235,-13.11A225.077,225.077 0,0 1,114.2 196.573,226.632 226.632,0 0,1 80.9,169.1a226.592,226.592 0,0 1,-27.474 -33.3A224.976,224.976 0,0 1,32.682 97.579,223.788 223.788,0 0,1 19.572,55.345 226.613,226.613 0,0 1,15 10L240,10L240,235Z"
        android:fillColor="#8BC34A"/>
  </group>
</vector>
```

**ic_bott_right.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="180dp"
    android:height="180dp"
    android:viewportWidth="250"
    android:viewportHeight="250">
  <group>
    <clip-path
        android:pathData="M0,0h250v250h-250z"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M10,10L235,10a226.678,226.678 0,0 1,-4.571 45.346A223.763,223.763 0,0 1,196.574 135.8a225.654,225.654 0,0 1,-98.993 81.519,223.933 223.933,45 0,1 -42.235,13.11A226.676,226.676 0,0 1,10 235L10,10Z"
        android:fillColor="#FFC107"/>
  </group>
</vector>
```

then in,
**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="DashBoard"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp">

        <!--Top_Left_Btn-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:onClick="OnClickAndroid"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_top_left">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_android"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Android"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--Top_Right_Btn-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:onClick="OnClickRide"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_top_right">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_ride"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Ride"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--Bottom_Left_Btn-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:onClick="OnClickBugs"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_bott_left">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bug"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Bugs"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--Bottm_Right_Btn-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:onClick="OnClickFitness"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_bott_right">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_fitness"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Fitness"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

& then create onClick method for buttons in

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.softwindevs.circularpiebuttons;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void OnClickAndroid(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Android Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void OnClickRide(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ride Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void OnClickBugs(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bugs Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void OnClickFitness(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fitness Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

& that's it, this is how you can do this magic

**Demo:**

### [image: Demo Image]

For all assets and full project code
Check out Github repo: [Click Here](https://github.com/Naik-Waqar/Custom-Circular-Pie-Buttons-Android)

GoodLuck:)

Comment: This is so perfect, gotta have a look on your project, I'll comment if there are any questions left! Thank you sir, stay save!

Comment: your welcom, Good Luck! @LosKayos